# Is there any systematic way to look for finite non-abelian simple groups? or any clever idea which makes them easier to find?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

I know that any finite abelian simple group like $G$ have the following properties:

1. $|G| = p$ where $p$ is a prime number.
2. $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (more general, we can say any simple abelian group is a cyclic group of prime order)

So we have a systematic way to find finite abelian simple groups, it's equivalent to find $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is a prime number.

What about finite non-abelian simple groups (like $A_5$ and $PSL(2,7)$), is there any systematic way to find them? or any clever idea which makes them easier to find?

Comment: The [ATLAS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATLAS_of_Finite_Groups) deserves a mention here.

Comment: There is probably no mathematical theorem which involves more strategies and clever ideas than the [Classification of finite simple groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups). You can start with investigating which $A_n$ and $PSL(n,q)$ are simple (and mutually non-isomorphic).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you! from the link that you shared: "every finite simple group is either cyclic or alternating, or it belongs to a broad infinite class called the groups of Lie type or else it is one of 26 exceptional groups(not including Tits group)" Did they guaranteed that there are only 26 exceptional groups, and no more exceptional groups can be found?

Comment: @Javad: Yes; that is part of the “classification of finite simple groups.” If we didn’t know the list of exceptions is complete, we wouldn’t *have* a classification.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yeah :)) Thanks!

Comment: Now , we in fact know all finite simple groups , but it was a very hard and long way until we arrived there.